# Eclipse JDT Core - Resolve generic return type for parameterised super method

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am v. inexperienced with the JDT apis, so would be great if someone could help me.

My question is how do I resolve the return type of the test method in the code below?

```
public interface BaseInterface<T> {
    T test();
}

public interface Messages extends BaseInterface<String> {}
```

I have tried all sorts of searching on google and stackoverflow (ASTParser, visitor, method bindings, etc, but can't seem to find an easy way to get the return type with JDT.

EDIT***
This is related to a bug I created/found a bug in https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/373, and was trying to fix it. My first time working with both JDT and gwt-eclipse plugin code, so it was just a stab, not sure if you can give any advice on it. The whole thing maybe need to be attacked in a slightly different way.

It calls the JavaModelSearch.findMethodInHierarchy first which grabs the IMethod, and passes that down, but then can't figure out the return type of T

Comment: What result do you expect? What have you tried? For clarifying the question: which method are you interested in - `BaseInterface.test()` or `Messages.test()`?

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I edited the question to include more info if that helps a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first find the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ITypeBinding` for interface "Messages".

From there you can navigate to `getSuperclass()` or in your case `getInterfaces()`. This should grant access to the **parameterized type** "BaseInterface<String>" *(note, that the light-weight JavaModel consisting of `IType`, `IMethod` etc. does not support the notion of a parameterized type as needed here)*.

From the latter binding, asking `getDeclaredMethods()` should answer the desired method "String test()" with return type "String" indeed.

For further inspiration you may want to look that the internal method [org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.dom.Bindings](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation/core%20extension/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/dom/Bindings.java)`.findMethodInHierarchy(ITypeBinding, String, ITypeBinding[])`.

Comment: Thanks a million for the details, I may try and sort that bug out once I get some free time out of work :)